# From xs:dateTime to std::chrono::timepoint

Tags: c++, xml, stl

I have a string written in `xs:datetime` format (https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_dtypes_date.asp) which I need to parse it and convert it to `std::chrono::timepoint`. In the standard libary there is `std::get_time` manipulator but it returns a `std::tm` and it does not parse milliseconds. I have many elements to parse so performances are also important. Is there anything else in either the standard library or Boost which I could use?

Comment: The code in the duplicate should work with an adjustment to the format string

Comment: @AlanBirtles that answer ignores milliseconds entirely

Comment: Howard Hinnant's answer doesn't